# PermissionError: [WinError 24] The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect

Tags: python, windows

When I do a `os.stat(source_directory)` or `Path(source_directory).glob` for any file or directory on a server, I get an error like this:

```
    for file_path in Path(source_directory).glob(pattern):
  File "C:\python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1140, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "C:\python\lib\pathlib.py", line 499, in select_from
    if not is_dir(parent_path):
  File "C:\python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1422, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1198, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
PermissionError: [WinError 24] The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect: '\\\\servername\\random\\directory'
```

The fileshare otherwise works perfectly fine. I can navigate in Windows Explorer, I can see directory/file properties, I can edit files etc. I can also read and write files using Python. It seems like the only thing that I unexpectedly cannot do is `os.stat` or any function that relies on `os.stat`.

I used to be able to use `os.stat` and my other colleagues can use it perfectly fine. We also had this problem on another computer, but a server restart fixed everything. The problem is that we are consultants, and this gives off the impression that our software is broken. It is quite a hassle to request a server restart. So I want to know what the actual problem is for my own sanity and to give a proper report on this.

What I have found:

- `os.stat` is a CPython `buildin` and implemented in c
- The same error code occurs if you open too many files within the same process (on Windows), [for example](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/68), and also replicated by myself:

```
file_handels = []
for i in range(10000):
    file_handels.append(open(f"foo/{i}"))
    
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'foo/8188'
```

- File interaction outside of the fileshare works fine (i.e. files on the harddrive)

Comment: I don't know why this happens but for me restarting PyCharm was enough, I didn't have to restart the computer

Comment: On our side we did not use an IDE, we were running python directly. The problem also magically disappeared